# Is every diffeomorphism an open map?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

Consider a diffeomorphism $f$ between two manifolds $M$ and $N$ (I refer only to the set of the manifold, the smoothness has not been specified). I know a diffeomorphism has the following properties:

1. $f$ is continuous
2. $f$ f is smooth
3. $f$ is a bijection
4. $f^{-1}$ is smooth

Is my definition fully correct? And does being a diffeomorphism make $f$ an open map?

Comment: Even more is true, every local diffeomorphism is an open map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An open map is just a function that maps an open set to an open set, whereas a continuous map satisfies that the preimage of an open set is an open set. Since a diffeomorphism $f$ is a continuous bijection, $f^{-1}$ is continuous. It follows that $f$ is an open map.

Since every homeomorphism is a continuous bijection, it is always an open map.

Comment: The continuity of $f^{-1}$  is enough for $f$ to be an open map.